# Apply Distinct and TOP(1) together 

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, join

My database table is something like this:

```
#tblMain
ID     Value  CreatedDate
________________________________________
1      25     2011-10-11 14:00:45.910
1      20     2011-10-26 14:00:12.910
2      27     2011-10-14 14:00:32.910
2      39     2011-10-14 14:00:28.910
2      54     2011-10-17 14:00:27.910
3      67     2011-10-25 14:00:16.910
3      79     2011-10-25 14:00:02.910
4      34     2011-10-26 14:00:14.910
4      24     2011-10-26 14:00:06.910
4      88     2011-10-26 14:00:47.910
5      12     2011-10-26 14:03:14.910
5      34     2011-10-26 14:04:06.910
5      55     2011-10-26 14:04:47.910
```

I'll get a list of IDs from a different table. So now I want to join the above table to this table based on ID, in such a way that I'll get 1  row for every distinct ID with a value field from the row with MIN(CreatedDate) i.e. oldest value for that particular ID. i.e. for every row, the selected row would be :

```
SELECT TOP(1) * from #tblMain ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC where ID = 1

SELECT TOP(1) * from #tblMain ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC where ID = 2...and so on.
```

Thus, my output should be like this:

```
ID  Value  CreatedDate               X   Y   Z(other columns from other tables)
_______________________________________________________________________________
1   25     2011-10-11 14:00:45.910
2   39     2011-10-14 14:00:28.910
3   79     2011-10-25 14:00:02.910
4   24     2011-10-26 14:00:06.910
5   12     2011-10-26 14:03:14.910
```

Trust me, I've tried my best to present my requirements as clearly as I possibly can, still if there's something unclear, let me know. Expecting a quick response. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
select m.ID, m.Value, m.CreatedDate, o.x, o.y, o.z
from (select tM.*, row_number() over (partition by ID order by CreatedDate) rn
      from #tblMain tM) m
left join otherTable o on m.ID = o.ID
where m.rn=1
```

Comment: You are missing () on row_number. But even after executing this query, I don't get distinct IDs, i.e. one row for every ID.

Comment: @PratikChandra: Thanks, I have corrected the omitted `()`. Are you getting missing IDs, or multiple rows for specific IDs? If the former, it sounds as though your other tables do not have corresponding records for all IDs - changing to an outer join (as in the amended query) should fix that. If the latter, it sounds as though your other tables have multiple corresponding records for some IDs - in which case, you need to refine the link criteria to the other tables.

Comment: @PratikChandra: Without the other table, this answer definitely gives you all the distinct IDs from your `#tblMain`. So, the issue must be with the other table, as Mark has already outlined for you.

Comment: @MarkBannister yes in my case the second table had multiple values with the same id. Changed it to some other table and the NEW query now works exactly as expected. These sql-joins always take a bite off me. Thanks, for rescuing.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T1.ID,T1.Value,T1.CreateDate, T2Col1,..
FROM T2 INNER JOIN 
   (
     SELECT ID,Value,CreateDate,
         Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY CreateDate) AS R1,
         Rank() OVER (ORDER BY CreateDate) AS R2
     FROM #tblMain
   ) T1 ON T2.ID = T1.ID
WHERE T1.R1 = T1.R2
```

Comment: It doesn't work. This query does not fetch ONLY the distinct IDs, whereas I need one row per ID based on the above mentioned selection criteria.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    Main.ID
    ,Main.Value
    ,Main.CreateDate
    ,MyOtherTable.X
    ,MyOtherTable.Y
    ,MyOtherTable.Z
from
    #tblMain Main
    inner join --this sub-query returns the unique ids with the min create dates
        (select
            ID
            ,MIN(CreateDate) as CreateDate
        from
            #tblMain
        group by
            ID) MinDates
        on MinDates.CreateDate = Main.CreateDate
            and MinDates.ID = Main.ID
    left join MyOtherTable
        on MyOtherTable.ID = Main.ID
```